# website not accessible with IIS6 while NAT is configured in Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, nat, rras

I have Windows2003 server configured with IIS 6. Until now it was working fine, but since I enabled NAT for my users to access the internet via this server, the website becomes unavailable. Note that I have two nics on the server one is WAN and 2nd is for LAN. Both IPs are behind the firewall.

If I stop the NAT then the website is available externally.

I tried to search the answer in this forum but didn't find appropriate one or maybe didn't properly understand.

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the server to do NAT, it doesn't know what you want to do with the ports on the public side.  You need to configure the server to let Internet users access the web site.  Here's how:

1. Open the `Routing and Remote Access` console
2. In the left pane, navigate to "IP Routing" -> "NAT/Basic Firewall"
3. In the right pane, right-click your WAN interface, and choose "Properties"
4. Go to the "Services and Ports" tab, and check the box for "Web Server (HTTP)" and/or "Secure Web Server (HTTPS)" as appropriate.  Put in the server's local IP address when prompted.
5. Click "OK" in the properties dialog, and close the Routing and Remote Access console.

You should now be able to access the web site from the WAN.